# adding strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps

I am working on creating a page using html and javascript.
I have json file that proves inputs to some of the contents i need.
What Im trying to do is to have address variable setup so that google map API can be displayed on my page.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address = cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name+" Company, "+locJson[jobLocID].location_name;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map, 
                title:address
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:200px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

above is part of the code.
the address variable has to look like

```
var address= "google Company, Austin, TX"
```

for google to recognize it properly.
if i know for fact that json returns exactly what im asking, what could be the problem here? how could i go about fixing it?

updated to ease some confusions.

when i view the source code on my website, i see that returned values are strings...

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address =Oracle+" Company, "+San Francisco, CA;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map, 
                title:address
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:200px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: this is very unclear. How are cmpyJson, Company, and locJson filled? what do they contain?  what results are you actually getting in the address variable.  There is not really enough here for anyone to help you.  Perhaps putting your code on jsfiddle would help show more context.  Also - what are the {{}} characters? those are not valid javascript objects...

Comment: @AllanNienhuis sorry. I put the whole google map part of the code on there and also added the source page view.

Comment: it looks like your templating language is confusing things. The source html you're supplying is not actually html, it is some template language.  cmpyJson is not a variable defined in javascript - it's probably defined someone on the server side in your templating framework.  What templating language are you using to create your html?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that all of these variables exist, the following line should be:

```
var address = cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name+" Company, "+locJson[jobLocID].location_name;
```

I just removed all of the curly brackets to make it syntactically correct.

Comment: I just edited the original post and added the source page of the page.
if i dont put {{}} around them, it is viewed on the source page as cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name, however, if i have {{}} around it, i get the actual strings back.

Answer (score 0):

If address is supposed to produce a string, and pull in parts from the cmpJson object, then do this:

```
 var address =cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name +" Company, "+ 
                    locJson[jobLocID].location_name;
```

You don't need the {{ }} around the JSON object references.  Also, if you plan to pass this into google, you need to encode it.

Comment: i just showed the google map part of the page as well as the source page of it. 
if i have {{}} around company_name and location_name, on the source page, it shows the actual string values, but if i dont have {{}}, it is shown as cmpyJson[jobCmpyID].company_name. so i was guessing that {{}} gets the string.